# IntelliSense bug c; changing to continue;

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I am using VScode with intelliSense for programming in c++. When I type a line ending with `c;` for example

```
int a=b+c;
```

Intellisense still offers me option `continue;`, so when I hit Enter to go to the next line, it changes `c;` to `continue;`, what I obviously don't like and don't want.

In general I would expect it wouldn't offer any options after semicolon. Can I somehow change this setting?